WebSocket Closes Unexpectedly in TTS Service with Multiprocessing and Asyncio
I am developing a TTS (Text-to-Speech) service using multiprocessing and asyncio in Python. My main application integrates other components using queue.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the WebSocket connection closes unexpectedly after some time.
Problem:
The WebSocket server starts successfully and initially works as expected, but after some interactions, it reports the following error and closes:
ERROR:root:received 1001 (going away); then sent 1001 (going away)
ERROR:root:no close frame received or sent
INFO:root:Cleaning up.
INFO:root:[Whisper INFO:] Connection Closed.
INFO:root:[Whisper INFO:] Exiting speech to text thread
 WARNING:root:[WhisperSpeech WARNING:] WebSocket is not open, cannot send data.

text_to_speech.py:
import functools
import logging
import time
import queue
import asyncio

import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
from websockets import serve, WebSocketServerProtocol
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosedError, ConnectionClosedOK
from whisperspeech.pipeline import Pipeline

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class WhisperSpeechTTS:
    RATE = 16000

    def __init__(self):
        self.speaker_embedding = None
        self.clients = {}
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    def initialize_model(self):
        self.pipe = Pipeline(s2a_ref='collabora/whisperspeech:s2a-q4-tiny-en+pl.model', torch_compile=True)
        self.last_llm_response = None

    async def run(self, host, port, audio_queue, should_send_server_ready):
        self.initialize_model()

        for _ in tqdm(range(3), desc="Warming up"):
            self.pipe.generate("Hello, I am warming up.", speaker=self.speaker_embedding)
        should_send_server_ready.value = True
        logging.info("[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Warmed up Whisper Speech torch compile model. Connect to the WebGUI now.")

        await self.start_server(host, port, audio_queue)

    async def start_server(self, host, port, audio_queue):
        while True:
            try:
                async with serve(functools.partial(self.handle_client, audio_queue=audio_queue), host, port):
                    logging.info("[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Server started, waiting for connections...")
                    await asyncio.Future()  # Run forever
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"[WhisperSpeech ERROR:] Server error: {e}")
            logging.info("[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Restarting server...")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay before restarting the server

    async def generate_audio(self, text):
        if not self.pipe:
            self.initialize_model()  # Ensure the model is initialized
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        audio = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.pipe.generate, text, self.speaker_embedding)
        return audio

    async def handle_client(self, websocket: WebSocketServerProtocol, audio_queue):
        client_id = id(websocket)
        self.clients[client_id] = TTSClient(websocket)

        try:
            await self.clients[client_id].handle_messages(audio_queue, self.generate_audio)
        except (ConnectionClosedError, ConnectionClosedOK):
            logging.info(f"[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Connection closed for client {client_id}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"[WhisperSpeech ERROR:] Client error: {e}")
        finally:
            await self.clients[client_id].cleanup()
            del self.clients[client_id]


class TTSClient:
    def __init__(self, websocket: WebSocketServerProtocol):
        self.websocket = websocket
        self.keep_alive_task = None

    async def handle_messages(self, audio_queue, generate_audio):
        self.keep_alive_task = asyncio.create_task(self.send_keep_alive())

        while True:
            try:
                llm_response = audio_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
                if audio_queue.qsize() != 0:
                    continue

                async with asyncio.Lock():  # Acquire lock to ensure only one message is processed at a time
                    llm_output = llm_response["llm_output"].strip()
                    eos = llm_response["eos"]
                    if not llm_output:
                        logging.info("[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Received empty LLM output, skipping TTS generation.")
                        continue

                    logging.info(f'[WhisperSpeech INFO:] LLM input for Whisper Speech: {llm_output}')
                    start_time_tts = time.time()
                    audio = await generate_audio(llm_output)

                    logging.info('[WhisperSpeech INFO:] Generated Whisper Speech audio.')
                    if audio is not None and eos:
                        if self.websocket.open:  # Ensure the websocket is open before sending
                            await self.websocket.send(audio.cpu().numpy().tobytes())
                        else:
                            logging.warning("[WhisperSpeech WARNING:] WebSocket is not open, cannot send data.")
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Small sleep to prevent high CPU usage
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"[WhisperSpeech ERROR:] Unexpected error: {e}")
                break

    async def send_keep_alive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                await self.websocket.ping()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"[WhisperSpeech ERROR:] Keep-alive ping failed: {e}")
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(30)  # Ping every 30 seconds

    async def cleanup(self):
        if self.keep_alive_task:
            self.keep_alive_task.cancel()
            await asyncio.gather(self.keep_alive_task, return_exceptions=True)
        logging.info("[WhisperSpeech INFO:] WebSocket connection closed, exiting loop.")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Small sleep to prevent high CPU usage

Observations:

The WebSocket server starts and connects successfully.
After a few interactions, the WebSocket closes unexpectedly.
The error log indicates no close frame received or sent.

Possible Issues:

Websocket resets issues causing intermittent disconnections.
A bug in the WebSocket handling logic.
Resource limitations or race conditions in the asynchronous code.

Questions:

How can I ensure the WebSocket remains open and stable throughout the session?
Are there any best practices to handle WebSocket connections in an asyncio and multiprocessing environment?
What could be causing the no close frame received or sent error, and how can I troubleshoot it effectively?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
